# R Lubridate pass a data table column value as the argument to month parameter instead of fixed integer

Tags: r, tidyverse, lubridate

I have a data table with two columns: a date column and another column with an integer value. I'd like to use the value in the integer column as the number of months to add to the date column. I have a feeling this may require something like apply [or lapply] to traverse the rows instead since passing a datatable column is not technically a scalar input value but rather a vector of multiple scalars. Any quick thoughts on how to achieve this?

works in my dataset

```
 dateTableProdKeep$"PROD_month"  <- dateTableProdKeep$"calc_new_date" %m+% months(1)
```

does not work when trying to pass a datatable column to the months argument

```
 dateTableProdKeep$"PROD_month"  <- dateTableProdKeep$"calc_new_date" %m+% months(dataTableProdKeep$"Month")
```

Here's a sample where passing 1 as argument to months works. I'd like that value to come from the Month column.

```
    library(lubridate)
    #library(tibble)
    
    calc_new_date <- c( "1/1/2022" , "1/31/2022" )
    Month <- c( 3 , 1 )
    
    dateTableProdKeep <- data.frame( calc_new_date , Month )
    
    dateTableProdKeep$"calc_new_date" <- as.Date( dateTableProdKeep$"calc_new_date" , format="%m/%d/%Y" )
    dateTableProdKeep
    
    dateTableProdKeep$"PROD_month" <- dateTableProdKeep$"calc_new_date" %m+% months(1)
    dateTableProdKeep

    dateTableProdKeep
      calc_new_date Month PROD_month
    1      1/1/2022     3 2022-01-01
    2     1/31/2022     1 2022-01-31
```

UPDATE code with solution example adapted from @MartinGal and applied to my original question:

```
    library(lubridate)
    #library(tibble)
    
    calc_new_date <- c( "1/1/2022" , "1/31/2022" )
    Month <- c( 3 , 1 )
    
    dateTableProdKeep <- data.frame( calc_new_date , Month )
    
    dateTableProdKeep$"calc_new_date" <- as.Date( dateTableProdKeep$"calc_new_date" , format="%m/%d/%Y" )
    dateTableProdKeep
    
    #dateTableProdKeep$"PROD_month" <- dateTableProdKeep$"calc_new_date" %m+% months(1)
    dateTableProdKeep
    
    
    
    #tibble(x = 1:100,date = seq(as.Date("2001-01-31"),by = "months", length = length(x)),z = date %m+% months(x))
    
    dateTableProdKeep$"new" <- dateTableProdKeep$"calc_new_date" %m+% months(dateTableProdKeep$"Month")
    dateTableProdKeep

calc_new_date Month        new
1    2022-01-01     3 2022-04-01
2    2022-01-31     1 2022-02-28
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example? You can use `dput(head(dateTableProdKeep))`, the paste the results in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're getting at:

```r
tibble(x = 1:100,date = seq(as.Date("2000-01-01"),by = "months", length = length(x)),z = date %m+% months(x))
```

Comment: @MartinGal The 'z' output provides the desired output (as opposed to where 'months' does not roll back dates in the case of Jan 31 to Feb 28 or Feb 29 depending on year. This approach works but need to adapt it to my specific dataset without requiring users to install tibble.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something when trying to adapt the tibble example from @MartinGal to the code I provided. I would like a solution working with my codebase provided so can't consider this answered yet.

Comment: @MartinGal I finally figured out how to adapt your code example. It turns out it was the original approach I was using except I misspelled the table name in the months parameter (i.e. I wrote dataTableProdKeep$"Month" instead of dateTableProdKeep$"Month" (data instead of date)). This worked:

`dateTableProdKeep$"new" <- dateTableProdKeep$"calc_new_date" %m+% months(dateTableProdKeep$"Month")`

Comment: @Chris that's actually Marc's code. I just edited the answer to improve formatting.